# HTML Marquee - Wrap text to fill browser window

Tags: html, css, marquee

I am using the marquee tag to make text scroll on my website. I am currently using placeholder text but the intention is to use an infinate dynamic feed.

I currently have it set up but the text only flows accross one line.

I would like to be able wrap the text so it fills the browser window with multiple lines of text

HTML:

```
<div id="scroll">
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="50">Here is some scrolling text... right to left!Here is some scrolling text... right to left!Here is some scrolling text... right to left!Here is some scrolling text... right to left!Here is some scrolling text... right to left!Here is some scrolling text... right to left!Here is some scrolling text... right to left!Here is some scrolling text... right to left!</marquee>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#scroll {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: black;
    color: cyan;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: ´<marquee>´ tag is de precated, use markee styles instead http://www.html-5.com/css/css-styles/css-style-properties/marquee-style.html

Comment: don't use <marquee> try http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/

Comment: None of these solutions do what I am looking for. I am looking for a way to have the overflow text of the marquee wrap to the next line once the first line is filled and continue to do so.

Comment: @JackCash Don't use marquee. Marquee doesn't do what you want. Forget about marquees. Find something that doesn't involve marquees. Rewrite this question so that it no longer contains the word "marquee".

Answer (score -1):

I used markup:

```
<div id="scroll">
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="50">
<p>Here is some scrolling text... right to left!</p>
<p>Here is some scrolling text... right to left!</p>
<p>Here is some scrolling text... right to left!</p>
<p>Here is some scrolling text... right to left!</p>
<p>Here is some scrolling text... right to left!</p>
<p>Here is some scrolling text... right to left!</p>
<p>Here is some scrolling text... right to left!</p>
<p>Here is some scrolling text... right to left!</p>
<p>Here is some scrolling text... right to left!</p>
</marquee>
</div>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kz9rp5ye/)